# puppet module init.pp using nodes.pp parameter

Tags: linux, puppet

Sorry if the title is confusing.

Some of my nodes.pp definitions contain:

```
node 'node.fqdn.blah' {
  $prod = "false"
  ..
  ..
  include my_service
}
```

In modules/my_service/manifests/init.pp, I want to state something like such:

```
..
..
..
      file { '/usr/local/my_service/tools/credentials.py':
        mode    => '0755',
        owner   => 'tomcat',
        group   => 'tomcat',
        ... insert "if prod" clause ...
        source  => 'puppet:///modules/my_service/creds.py',
        require => Package['my_service'],
        notify  => Service['tomcat7'],
      }
..
..
..
```

This way when I run update on my staging nodes the credentials don't get changed.

Is there a puppet solution to this, or should I just make my file immutable on the non-prod nodes?

Thanks

---

Response #1

Thanks for the heads up on nodes.pp, this is the env I'm dealing with. The file is updated by puppet because I do control it. I control it in the production env because I update the password routinely. However in my non-prod environments, this file should not be touched. I want it to continue updating as it does (for prod), but not for the other envs.

Comment: First `nodes.pp` has been discouraged for a long time now. Second, why do you think that file would be changed by Puppet unless you control it?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want Puppet to modify the file's *content* in non-prod environments?  What if the file doesn't exist (yet) at all?  And do you want to manage other attributes of the file regardless?  What do you mean by "immutable" in this context?